# how to do not send query params from angular to node

Tags: node.js, angular, api, parameters, request

I want to search data with query params that I get them from select option, if they are empty I do not want to send them with request.

**angular component**

```
  genre = "";
  platform = "";

  queryparams = {
    genre: this.genre,
    platform: this.platform
  }


public selectTopByPlaytime() {
    this.gameService.selectTopByPlaytime(this.queryparams)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          //next() callback
          console.log('response received')
          console.log(response);
          this.topGamesTime = response;
        },
        (error) => {                              //error() callback
          console.error('Request failed with error')
          this.errorMessage = error;
        },
        () => {                                   //complete() callback
          console.error('Request completed')      //This is actually not needed 
        })
  }


  onChangeGenre(event: any) {
    this.genre = event
    this.queryparams.genre = this.genre
    this.selectTopByPlaytime()
    this.selectTopByUsers()

  }
```

**Angular service**

```
  public selectTopByPlaytime(queryParams?): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "topbyplaytime", { params: queryParams }).pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I don't find a way to stop sending params if they are null or empty

here how I catch them from express server :

```
const selectTopByPlaytime = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const options = req.query
    try {
        const data = await gameService.selectTopByPlaytime(options)
        res.send(data)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` })
    }
})

const selectTopByPlaytime = async (options) => {
    let topGames = games
    console.log(options);
    if (options.genre != undefined || options.genre != 'null') {
        topGames = topGames.filter(game => game.genre == options.genre)
    }
    if (options.platform != undefined || options.platform != 'null') {
        topGames = topGames.filter(game => game.platforms.includes(options.platform))
    }

    return _.chain(topGames)
        .groupBy('game')
        .map((value, key) => {
            return {
                'game': key,
                'playTime': _.reduce(value, function (memo, i) { return memo + i.playTime; }, 0),
                'genre': value[0].genre,
                'platforms': value[0].platforms,
            };
        })
        .sortBy((i) => { return -i.playTime; })
        .first(5).value()
}
```

when I test my api with postman and set the params every thing work fine, I cant catch what's the problem when I run my angular app , data always empty ! any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object.Assign(target, source). It will copy properties from source object to target object

For more information [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let queryparams = {};

if (this.genre) {
      queryparams = Object.assign(queryparams, {genre: this.genre});
    }

if (this.platform) {
      queryparams = Object.assign(queryparams, {platform: this.platform});
    }
```